# Plot graphs in R by grouping the data in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, subset

Assume I have this kind of data:

```
distance <- c(134.2, 433.34, 332.12, 543.12, 333.12)
road.type <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
A <- c(2.3, 3.1, 4.4, 2.2, 1.4)
B <- c(0.33, 0.56, 0.45, 0.55, 0.98)

random.list <- data.frame(distance, road.type, A, B)
```

And I want, on the same plot, to draw for example the combination distance~A by classifying the data by road.type. So, the plot should contain two lines actually, one line will express the distance~A data given that road.type = 1 and the second will illustrate the distance~A data given that road.type = 0.

What I have come up with is this:

```
random.list.sp1 <- random.list[random.list$road.type == "1"]
```

But what I get in return is not a table that contains rows which only have road.type = 1, but instead a table that contains all rows but without the road.type column.

Also in general, is there a quick way to modify the data by a given column for any other kind of plot? Particularly, can I use the proposed technique in pairs() or scatterplot() etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Your road.type needs to be something other than a number (e.g. a factor) to separate the plot into 2 series.

```
distance <- c(134.2, 433.34, 332.12, 543.12, 333.12)
road.type <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
A <- c(2.3, 3.1, 4.4, 2.2, 1.4)
B <- c(0.33, 0.56, 0.45, 0.55, 0.98)

random.list <- data.frame(distance, road.type, A, B)

random.list$road.type <- as.factor(random.list$road.type)
library(tidyverse)

data <- gather(random.list, distance, road.type)
names(data) <- c("distance", "road_type", "class", "value")
data <- data %>% filter(class == "A")
ggplot(data, aes(distance, value, color = road_type)) + geom_line()
```